# How to Write Run Script in Build Phase in IOS Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am working on a framework , I want to make a build of that which should work on both iphone-simulator and iphone-device(i386 and ARM Architecture).

So i need  run script which will build framework for both iphone-simulator and iphone-device and combine binary of both to make universal framework.

Answer (score 3):

In order to write a Run Script in Build Phase follow the following steps :

1. Add a Run Script in iOS you need select your project on the left side in project and then go to "Build Phases".

[image]

2. Click on the "+" button on the setting and select "New Run Script Phase"

[image]

3. You can now add any script inside the "Run Script Section"

[image]

**Note**: In the "Shell" option under the "Run Script" header type the path of executable where your script should run.

These steps are also present in the following link :

http://runscriptbuildphase.com/

Comment: Let me know if you have any issue in following these steps

Comment: I know where to write run script. I was asking for   run script which will build framework for both iphone-simulator and iphone-device and combine binary of both to make universal framework.